# Visual Studio 2013 override launching individual files or fix MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

My problem is a little messy, and difficult to explain, so please ask for more detail if I'm explaining poorly.

In Visual Studio 2013, I created a Web API project using MVC routing.  When I launch my project by pressing the Internet Explorer button, it loads the page just fine every time.  However, if I'm viewing my index html file in the main window, it appends "/Home/index" (the relative filepath) to the URL.  Normally, I would not care about this, however, it similarly *prepends* "/Home/index" to every web request made from that webpage, which obviously breaks every subsequent request.

In other words, I think my problem is that when I'm viewing my index page and launch my project, it modifies the URL.  I either need to change it so that it always kicks off the index page with no extension (i.e. http: //local host, like every non-html file does) or I need to fix the routing to not automatically prepend /Home/index.

Currently I am able to work around it by simply pressing launch from a non-html file, but this is inconvenient to remember every time I launch the project, as well as explain to anyone else that I demo the project to.

Here's an example call:

```
    var baseURL = 'api/restweb/';
    var uriScenario = baseURL + 'scenario';
    request = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "GET",
        url: uriScenario,
        // return handling and other information here...
    });
```

Comment: To what URL do you make the request? Make sure it begins with `/` to indicate the root. At least, I guess your problem actually is your API call goes to `/Home/Index/api/SomeApi` and you want it to go to `/api/SomeApi`. Please show the code making a request, and indicate what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I added an example call, but I'm not sure from your response that I've explained my problem well enough.

When I hit launch on any file that isn't my html files, the requests will go to `/api/SomeApi` just like I want.  But if I launch the index file, all requests instead go through `/Home/Index/api/SomeApi`.

Comment: Your code indicates my guess was right: your `baseURL` has to start with a slash (`/api/restweb`).

Comment: Why does that matter?  It fixed it.  If you want to post it as a separate answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: how can you launch index file in mvc...it is a cshtml file. you can not directly call it..you need to call action that will return this view...can you please explain how are you launching index file ?

Comment: I press the button in Visual Studio that says "Internet Explorer" (or whatever browser you set it to).  Not really sure what else to say - it's a button displayed by default, for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I launch my project by pressing the Internet Explorer button, it loads the page just fine every time. However, if I'm viewing my index html file in the main window, it appends "/Home/index" (the relative filepath) to the URL.

That's why all URLs in MVC should be absolute. An absolute URL starts with a `/`, indicating the URL should be appended to the host name only, and not the current path.

Your code shows:

```
var baseURL = 'api/restweb/';
```

This request will work when visiting the URL `http://example.com`, because the AJAX request will be made to `http://example.com/api/restweb/`.

This code will however only work when you run it at the root of `http://example.com/` (or any host), and as you've encountered not when any path is present, such as `/Home/Index`.

Because `/Home/Index` ultimately is the same page as at `/` (because it's the default route), and because you will want to be able to use this code on other pages, prefix the URL with a slash:

```
var baseURL = '/api/restweb/';
```

Now even when this code runs at `http://example.com/Some/Other/Controller/`, the API request still will go to `http://example.com/api/restweb/`.